# Let $2Z:= \left \{ 2k | k\in Z \right \}$ be the collection of all even integers. Show that $N \cup2Z$ is denumerable.

Tags: elementary-set-theory

> Let $2Z:= \left \{ 2k | k\in Z \right \}$ be the collection of all
> even integers.
>
> Show that $N \cup2Z$ is denumerable.

I first try to build a map $f:N\rightarrow N \cup2Z$ to be bijective, to show $N \cup2Z$ is denumberable.

However, since all even integers $2Z$ contains negative integers, and $N$ doesn't, I do not think they would have the same cardinality.

Hence there is no such bijective map.

I am wondering if I've missed something here.

Some hint or correction would be very helpful.

Comment: $\{0,1,2,-2,3,4,-4,5,6,-6,7,8,-8,9,10,-10,\dots\}$

Comment: Even by naive arguments, one might say "$2\Bbb Z$ has half of the integers, namely the even half" and "$\Bbb N$ has half of the integers, namely the non-negative half"... even a naive argument should have thought they were the same cardinality since they have the same relative density.  Of course, we know that every infinite subset of $\Bbb Q$ has the same cardinality as $\Bbb N$, including $2\Bbb Z$ as well as $\Bbb Z$ so arguments appealing to relative density aren't actually useful here.

Answer (score 1):

To emphasize, "*our set having a bijection with $\Bbb N$*" can be rephrased as "*our set can be listed in a sequence, every element eventually appearing in the sequence exactly once*"

Our set in question here is $2\Bbb Z\cup \Bbb N$.

An example of a sequence which touches each element exactly once might be something like:

$$0,1,2,-2,3,4,-4,5,6,-6,7,8,-8,9,10,-10,11,12,-12,\dots$$

If you give me your favorite number like $42$ that you know to be in the set, I could tell you where in the sequence it would be.  (*Counting starting from zero, it would be the 62'nd term in the sequence*)

Now... you might ask, "*why does a sequence like this imply there is a bijection?*"  To that, you have to understand what a sequence *is in the first place*.  The sequence *is the bijection*.  A sequence, formally, is a function $f$ from $\Bbb N$ to a set.  The "first element of the sequence" is simply $f(1)$ and the "second element of the sequence" is simply $f(2)$ and so on...  We just choose to short-hand and write the sequence as $0,1,2,-2,3,4,-4,\dots$ rather than $f(x)=\begin{cases}0&\text{if}~x=0\\1&\text{if}~x=1\\2&\text{if}~x=2\\-2&\text{if}~x=3\\3&\text{if}~x=4\\\vdots\end{cases}$.  The sequence will be bijective per our selection of the sequence being one in which *every element eventually appears in our sequence exactly once*.

The only challenge remaining should be to formalize the sequence to write it in a more compact form.

> Further hint, try writing it in the form $f(x)=\begin{cases}\dots&\text{if }x\equiv 0\pmod{3}\\\dots&\text{if }x\equiv 1\pmod{3}\\\dots &\text{if }x\equiv 2\pmod{3}\end{cases}$

---

Alternatively, if you merely wish to show they are countable and are willing to skip finding an explicit bijection, you can see that your set is a superset of $\Bbb N$ and a subset of $\Bbb Z$, both of which you should know by example are countable.  Your statement though "*However, since all even integers 2Z contains negative integers, and N doesn't, I do not think they would have the same cardinality*" implies to me that you are unaware of the fact that $\Bbb Z$ is also countable.

Comment: Thank you for answering in the most demeaning way possible. Now I've fully aware how stupid and uninformed I am. I would now quit school or ever bothering or trying as I apparently "don't even know Z is also countable".

Comment: @Aimee If you choose to take it as demeaning and hurtful versus helpful and uplifting, that is your choice.  A part of the learning process is to have your mistakes pointed out to you and have your own flawed arguments turned against you so that you can learn from them and grow past them.  Otherwise, you risk repeating the same mistakes.  You should learn to accept that this is done out of a desire to help, not malice.

Comment: no worries. I would never made the same mistake again. As I won't bother trying ever again. Congratulation. You've rid someone off math who "don't even know Z is countable", " Can't even make a naive argument" and obviously don't "understand sequence in the first place".

Comment: If you've chosen to give up, go ahead.  Mathematics and college in general isn't for everyone.  If you are unhappy in academics, there are plenty of opportunities that don't involve them... If, however, you choose to grow up and continue to try to further your understanding, we are always here to help.  *Everyone* is a beginner in a field at some point and is prone to making mistakes.  What matters is how you choose to act when such mistakes are pointed out, whether you try to improve or whether you give up.  The same is true for life in general.  The general consensus is it is better to try.

Comment: After practically saying I can't even make a naive argument and the equivalence of telling someone "you don't even know addition", you are now here saying "everyone is a beginner at some point"? wow. I wonder how you'd feel if you were learning English while holding the alphabet chart then someone just decided to replied to your genuine question by "it tells me you are unaware of ABC".

Comment: You don't know me. You don't know how many times I've tried. I was in a really good place before your "naive" comment. I was enjoying learning countables and sequence and open sets and all. I used to really like math. And then I met more and more people just like you, who uses "helping" to justify being condescending and demeaning.  So I stop asking question. I need help. Not someone flaunting their knowledge in front of my face to make themselves feel superior. 

I'm just done.

Comment: I need to update some of the comments I made a day ago since I wrote them under extreme anger. 
First of all, No. you don't get to get up on the high horse and say “everyone is a beginner at once, we're here to help” right after mocking me for not understanding the basics. It's no different than making snarky comments on people's appearance then backtrack it with “ I'm just trying to help you improve”. And no, it is not helpful or uplifting. You know full well how you are coming off as with that “ it tells me you don't know...” and all the excessive comments.

Comment: Second, for your information, I do know Z is countable. The question is literally the exercise right after that. What you did is not “point out my mistake as part of the learning process”, you don't know enough about me to do such a thing.You are being demeaning and condescending. Sure it wasn't out of malice. You are just having your ego stroked, at the expense of a beginner.

Comment: I read somewhere you were a TA. I genuinely hope you don't treat your students like this. I had a TA just like this, who strives on making sure you knew how little he thinks of you and “your argument”, and whoever dare to make a dumb mistake that “college and math isn't for everyone”. He did it under the exact same pretence, “so you can learn to grow”.  I had to drop both class that year for having dark thoughts. And they wonder why people keep dropping out of their program not other departments’.

Comment: Lastly, it is just a learning process to have your mistake point out to you. Otherwise you risk repeating the same mistake. Please do learn from them and grow pass them. There is a line between demeaning and helpful. FYI, I ment to send this as a private message, but I guess you can't do that here. So regardless whether you'll read this or not, I'll just leave it here.

Comment: When helping in person, I can more easily ask leading questions and wait before moving to the punchline.  With no guarantee you would respond in a timely manner I went ahead and concluded the arguments.  In any event, the way you are responding to criticism is abnormal and took a much darker turn than I would have ever imagined.  I sincerely hope you seek counseling and professional help.

Comment: I did seek help. You wanna know why I can't recall property of sequence off to top of my head? You know why I can't see how “obvious” the answer is? Cause I take a hiatus from school to seek professional help. I'm starting over. Surely now you can see why what you see as a punchline, is a slap on the face to me. Words have consequence. Please don't ever answer someone else’s question the way you did mine in the future.